# Best way to run multiple calculations simultaneously?

Tags: performance-tuning, front-end, notebooks, kernel

I feel this question probably has been asked before, but I can't find a thread with a clear enough answer. Let me know if you can help locate anything useful.

As the title suggests, I want to run different calculations at the same time. Typically, we have program A running now, which will last for hours. In the meantime, I need to calculate B, maybe a different version of A or some completely different stuff. How to start B completely independently from A?

Firstly, a new notebook doesn't help. It only waits until A finishes. **This is probably the main question.**
Secondly, by 'independently', I mean if A and B happen to have certain same variable names or so, surely we want to avoid any possible side effects. And I usually start my programs with `` ClearAll["Global`*"]; ``.  But running B had better not clean anything in A. In this sense, maybe this command is no longer a good practice?
(Optional) Thirdly, with parallelization. If A uses 2 cores and B uses another 2 cores, is the above still possible?

I remember that one can open a new instance of MMA in Windows, but this doesn't seem available in Mac.

Comment: Regarding your variables you should have a look at [`Module`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html). With this you can treat your variables inside `Module`as local and they won't be defined outside it.

Comment: For your parallelization needs, you might find [`ParallelSubmit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelSubmit.html) to do the trick.

Comment: `ClearAll["Global`*"];` is indeed not a good practice in general. As rowsi suggests, get into the habit of localizing variables with `Module`, `Block`, or `With` in greater projects.

Comment: If you have enough RAM, you may start Mathematica twice.

Comment: In mathematica, you can see a command for configuring kernels in the `Evaluation` menu. Add a kernel there, and assign it to a new notebook.